# Click at button > Add div > In div button to remove div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page where it needs to be possible to add and then remove added divs. The divs can't just hide because its should contains settings so when delete the div/divs = the settings in this div/divs also gets deleted. The divs that gets loaded in/added are: `#settings1` `#settings2` `#setting3`.

In the page there is a button that should add the divs (example: click 3 times to add `#settings1` `#settings2` `#settings3`:

```
<a href="" class="design_button">Click here to add more divs</a>
```

Then there is a div that should receive the contents (`#settings1` `#settings2` `#settings3`) when its getting loaded in:

```
<div id="this_div_contains_settings">Here the #settings gets loaded in, then deleted if its not needed anymore</div>
```

Then in another page (content.html) there is the div #settings containing settings:

```
<div id="settings1">Some forms etc.</div>
<div id="settings2">Some forms etc.</div>
<div id="settings3">Some forms etc.</div>
```

In those divs there is a button that will remove the specific div after its been added.

```
<a href="" class="design_button">Remove this div</a>
```

---

**Basically:** Click the "Click here to add more divs" button to add multiple `#settings` divs into the div `#this_div_contains_divs`. Click on the button "Remove this div" in the `#settings` div to remove the current div.

<!- Picture is 404 **I made a picture to describe how I mean: [http://imgur.com/DVPSR](https://imgur.com/DVPSR)** ->

I need some help with:

Load in the content `#settings1` `#settings2` `#settings3` to `#this_div_contains_settings` by clicking on a button then delete the current div by clicking on a button in that div.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: You can't have multiple divs with `id="settings"` - you need to use `class="settings"` instead

Comment: Then the button "Click here to add more divs" should load in example #settings1 #settings2 #settings3 insteed.

Comment: It's not the most intuitive solution to use same class for both adding and removing the divs.

Comment: I think it probably just better to add different divs with "same" content.

Comment: Where is your "another page (content.html)" ??? How are you thinking you should achieve this client side? Do you wnat to store the settings in a cookie or what kind of AJAX solution (based on your tag) are you looking at?

Comment: Yes the settings is stored in cookies. I edit the post now so I guess now the solution maybe is possible? Multiple different settings divs.

Comment: since you don't provide what you want to store in the cookies except the div numbers it's hard to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery for your index.html page would look like something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="design_button add">Click here to add more divs</a>
<div id="this_div_contains_settings"></div>
```

jQuery (you need to load jQuery version higher than 1.7.2 for on() to work):

```
$(function(){
   var number = 1;
   $('a.add').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#this_div_contains_settings').append('<div id="settings'+number+'">Some forms etc.<a href="#" class="design_button">Remove this div</a></div>');
      number++;
   });
   $('#this_div_contains_settings').on('click','a.design_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().remove();
   });
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WdcTK/

Then adding data to cookies remain...

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to receive the #settings1, #settings2, #settings3 from content.html?

Comment: Sure, but you need to store data in your cookies. But I dont know what data you are working with here... ("some forms" are a bit vague)

Comment: Its just some select-values from selectboxes.

Comment: So how do you work with the cookies today? Cookies are of course a bit limited storage since they consist of simple name=value pairs even if there are ways to store arrays. Also what will actually trigger the storage? Form changes and/or add/remove buttons? I always work with server-side techniques/ajax. Doing an complete cookie solution here is too advanced what I think. You need to add your own code and get help to debug it instead...

Comment: I understand what you say but I am not a backend coder. I think its better to first learn to load in a div, the learn how delete a div etc and then finally I maybe can get this solution to work. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: Small error. Corrected, see my edit and also: http://jsfiddle.net/WdcTK/ But making a quite advanced cookie storage and then convert it to backend ajax doesn't make sense to me. Ask yr backend people to help...

Comment: Can you please just explain fast and simple? I really want to understand even if I dont write all the code. That jsfiddle worked great but is it possible to make it load in #settings1,2,3, etc then after all three divs are loaded in it dont load in "empty" divs? See how I mean here http://jsfiddle.net/WdcTK/4/, I mean after the three first divs are loaded in there should be nothing more. Thanks for your help. Edit: Maybe possible to remove the text "Add some more divs" after those three divs are loaded? Then if remove one div the text shows again?

Comment: Sorry, the solution you looking for now requires me to rewrite my code quite a lot. Just adding 3 divs requires some more thought and also adding array data with values from your selectboxes in cookies would be quite much coding. I'm not your man here... :(

Comment: I understand, thanks for your code and help. Think your code example can be useful if I decide to try write a similar script myself with help from jquery-guides etc.